# Plot n series on same plot not overlapping

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a time series of prices, 2000 entries.
I have created 12 vectors where each one contains only the data for one month. They don't have the same length, vary about 20 values between 160 and 180 values.

So now I need to plot all these vectors in the same plot, in sequence of course, starting with January data, and a little space in between, and on the x-axis put the month names (which I have in an array ['jan' 'feb' etc]

For an example click on the link and scroll down to seasonal subseries plot
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc443.htm

[image]

Comment: This time series of 2000 rows I suppose has a column with a datestamp and a column with prices, right?

Comment: Yes :) I guess you'll tell me I didn't have to separate them?

Comment: Oh god i just found this http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/stats/examples/time-series-regression-of-airline-passenger-data.html... let's see if I can make it work with different lengths

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a similar graph to the above, you can insert a row of NaNs after each month. Since, each month has a different number of rows, you cannot simply reshape, concatenate NaNs, and reshape back.

Suppose you have a timestamps in the first column and some data in the second column:

```m
data                = [(now-11:now+13)' rand(25,1)];

% Count in 'idx' when each year-month pair ends 
[y,m]               = datevec(data(:,1));
[~, idx]            = unique([y,m],'rows','last');

% Preallocate expanded Out with NaN separations between each month
szData              = size(data);
Out                 = NaN(szData(1) + numel(idx)-1,2);

% Reposition 'data' within 'Out'
pos                 = ones(szData(1),1);
pos(idx(1:end-1)+1) = 2;
Out(cumsum(pos),:)  = data;

% Example plot
plot(Out(:,1),Out(:,2))
set(gca,'Xtick',data([1 11 12 25],1))
datetick('x','dd-mmm','keepticks')
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Oleg, thank you so much for your answer, however I didn't fully manage to make it work for me, am a lousy programmer...the graph looked good but the numbers were still "in timeseries order". So using spaghetti code I created 9 arrays (2005- 2013) of year data, then a for loop that calculated avg for every month in the year array, put everything in a matrix, then with all_years1 = NaN(size(all_years) + 1) % Preallocate space. Then all_years1 = [all_years(:,:),NaN(size(all_years,1),1),all_years(:,10:end)] to add col of NaN at the end, allyears = reshape(all_years1',120,1) and plotted...